# Where do I post Stack Exchange-specific coding issues?

Tags: support, scope

I'm working on user-side CSS rules for better viewing of Stack Exchange.  I noticed there was no `issue`/`bug` tag on Stack Overflow.  I thought to post the question here, but I felt I would have a broader audience if using Stack Overflow itself.

Answer (score 2):

If the question is broadly-relevant and concerns programming, then it should be asked on Stack Overflow. In other words…it is irrelevant *why* you writing the CSS. If you have an issue with CSS code, then you should ask for help on Stack Overflow.

If your question is *unique* to Stack Overflow and unlikely to be broadly-relevant, then it should be asked here on Meta. Issues/bugs relating to Stack Overflow itself (and/or its design) are to be posted on the Meta site, not the main site.

Just about anything is going to have a broader audience if you post it on Stack Overflow. It gets [lots of views](https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com). But that is not enough reason to post a question there. You also have to ensure that it is on-topic. I understand that that this is what you're doing now, but reading that comment in your question is kind of like fingernails on a chalkboard to me.

I realize this answer is somewhat vague. The rules seem pretty simple to me, so your best judgment should be enough to figure out the appropriate site. It is difficult for me to be any more specific here, since you didn't give us any more detail about the question you wanted to ask.